# how to make intent chooser for xml in android

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, intentfilter

i tried a lot of things, but i cant make it work, i had an application, and i want when there is an XML in the email, or maybe file explorer or more else, i want my app in the popup of the intent chooser, i cant make it work, anyone has a clue?
btw lets say i make it work, so how i can "handle" when people choose my app in onCreate() to load the information.
here its part of my app i tried a lot of things

```
<i><application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/xml"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*xml" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application> </i>
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do. Please restate.  This part is confusing :  i want when there is an XML in the email, or maybe file explorer or more else, i want my app in the popup of the intent chooser

Answer (score 0):

Try being a little more broad with your filter, e.g.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

    <data android:mimeType="text/xml"/>
    <data android:scheme="content" android:mimeType="text/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml"/>
    <data android:scheme="file" android:mimeType="text/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:mimeType="text/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml"/>
    <data android:scheme="https" android:mimeType="text/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: i figure out i need create another intent filter only for VIEW instead MAIN

Answer (score 0):

Other thing you could do is catch the intents in broadcast receiver and rebroadcast as neededed.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code i use, i figure out i need to create another intent filter for view

```
 <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:mimeType="application/xml" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/xml" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            </intent-filter>
```